# MySql join multiple select

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

I'm trying to make a select, joining the columns of the table1 and the values from table2.

I'm not really sure about the statement I need to do it, but, look, I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

Comment: You have to have the same number of columns, types (try that part), and the same order for UNION.

Comment: I think is not an union statement what I'm looking for here... :/ let me edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all these columns on each row, you should be using a `join`, not `union`. E.g.:

```
SELECT colum1, column2, column3, column4, column5
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: I just want two columns from table2